# Using multiple databases for Mediawiki

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I want to use mediawiki because I love what it provides. However I am limited to MySQL databases of 1GB each (I can have unlimited 1GB MySQL databases, through 1&1).  My size calculations require multiple databases, probably 15-25 to start, with more down the road.  Is it possible to do this?  If it is possible am I going to have to basically rewrite mediawiki where necessary, or make an extension?

I'm good with PHP so rewriting doesn't scare me, I just don't have a lot of time so I am trying to figure out the fastest approach.

From what I am thinking, I would like a search DB, User DB, info DB, and many greek alphabet databases. To where the search DB, is for searching pages, with a 1 to many relationship to the info DB, that then tells the PHP script where to go to get the info, such as search for 'Sirius' which then it finds what DB is related to Sirius and points it to say Gamma DB, where the actual information is stored.  User DB, is self explanatory, and I already have a good amount of examples through Joomla<->MediaWiki, to do this, so this isn't a concern of mine.

Comment: May I ask what your monthly costs are? I mean, there are offers for less than 5 Euros a month (e.g. https://www.netcup.de/bestellen/produkt.php?produkt=1052), so the question is, if it's really worth the effort hacking MediaWiki itself instead of searching for a provider who offers you what you need.

Comment: I pay roughly the same, for one of the older packages at 1and1.  I haven't upgraded my package because my original package offers more than the current packages that cost twice as much.  I guess its the glory of having an older package, and wanting to keep all my domains on one site to avoid another monthly payment.

Comment: do it without a database, do it with sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try and make each wiki use the same database, but with a different database prefix; the tables will all be on the same database but there will be no conflict, wiki1_user, wiki2_user etc.

However, what you're trying to do here is called a [wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family) or wiki farm. You should try to reduce code duplication etc. and there are several approaches around you can try to adopt, for instance this [Simple Farm](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Simple_Farm) extension.